# How to run a python script constantly on Windows 10 best practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to run a script on windows 10 machine that I set a server in my LAN.
I would like for the script to restart 30 seconds after it finished, forever.
Is there any better way then putting it in an infinite while loop?

Here is my code:

```
import Time 
while True:
     print("Here does all the things it's supposed to")
     # Does something
     time.wait(30)
```

While this works, I'm worried that it will affect performance and maybe memory of of the server or slowing it down in time.

Is there any better way to run a code forever in a loop in windows, perhaps with some command for terminal or any other option better then mine?
Kindly note the machine is a windows 10, 64 Bit arch, not a linux machine.

Comment: Use Task Scheduler https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/

Comment: What is this `time.wait(30)` ? Do you mean `time.sleep(30)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up a term more famously known as a "chron job" 
Heres an article I found out which can help: https://www.technipages.com/scheduled-task-windows

using "chron" you can schedule when to run a script at exact date and time. Or choose how to run code in infinite loop. You can also decide when to stop the script